# Football Guaranteed Relegation/Promotion Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, depth-first-search

I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the calculation of guaranteed promotion in football (soccer) for a given football league table.  It seems like there is a lot of structure to the problem so the exhaustive solution is perhaps slower than necessary.

In the problem there is a `schedule` (a list of pairs of teams) that will play each other in the future and a `table` (map) of points each team has earned in games in the past.  I've included a sample real life points table below.  Each future game can be won, lost or tied and teams earn 3 points for a win and 1 for a tie.  Points (Pts) is what ultimately matters for promotion and `num_of_promoted_teams` (positive integer, usually around 1-3) are promoted at the end of each season.

[image: Sample table]

The problem is to determine which (if any) teams are currently guaranteed promotion.  Where guaranteed promotion means that no matter the outcome of the final games the team must end up promoted.

```
def promoted(num_of_promoted_teams, table, schedule):

   return guaranteed_promotions
```

I've been thinking about using depth first search (of the future game results) to eliminate teams which would lower the average but not the worst case performance.  This certainly help early in the season, but the problem could become large in mid-season before shrinking again near the end. It seems like there might be a better way.

Comment: Are there tiebreakers?

Comment: Goal difference is a common tiebreaker.  Though since a game could technically have infinite goals I suspect the case could be covered by a couple if/then statements near the end of the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constraint solver should be fast enough in practice thanks to clever pruning algorithms, and hard to screw up. Here’s some sample code with the OR-Tools CP-SAT solver.

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


def promoted(num_promoted_teams, table, schedule):
    for candidate in table.keys():
        model = cp_model.CpModel()
        final_table = table.copy()
        for home, away in schedule:
            home_win = model.NewBoolVar("")
            draw = model.NewBoolVar("")
            away_win = model.NewBoolVar("")
            model.AddBoolOr([home_win, draw, away_win])
            model.AddBoolOr([home_win.Not(), draw.Not()])
            model.AddBoolOr([home_win.Not(), away_win.Not()])
            model.AddBoolOr([draw.Not(), away_win.Not()])
            final_table[home] += 3 * home_win + draw
            final_table[away] += draw + 3 * away_win
        candidate_points = final_table[candidate]
        num_not_behind = 0
        for team, team_points in final_table.items():
            if team == candidate:
                continue
            is_behind = model.NewBoolVar("")
            model.Add(team_points < candidate_points).OnlyEnforceIf(is_behind)
            model.Add(candidate_points <= team_points).OnlyEnforceIf(is_behind.Not())
            num_not_behind += is_behind.Not()
        model.Add(num_promoted_teams <= num_not_behind)
        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
        status = solver.Solve(model)
        if status == cp_model.INFEASIBLE:
            yield candidate


print(*promoted(2, {"A": 10, "B": 8, "C": 8}, [("B", "C")]))
```

Comment: It works but I'll have to read some documentation to figure out why it is fast.  I'm guessing it is not guaranteed to find the solution?

Comment: @rhaskett It's about as guaranteed as anything ever is in software; the question is how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an alternative solution that is less extensible and probably slower in exchange for being self-contained and predictable.

This solution consists of an algorithm to test whether a particular team can finish behind a particular set of other teams (assuming unfavorable tie-breaking), wrapped in a loop over pairs consisting of a top-k team ℓ and a set of k teams W that might or might not finish ahead of ℓ (where k is the number of promoted teams).

If there were no draws, then we could use bipartite matching. Mark ℓ as having lost its remaining matches and mark W as having won their matches against teams not in W. On one side of the bipartite graph, there are nodes corresponding to matches between members of W. On the other side, there are zero or more nodes for each team in W, corresponding to the number of matches that that team must win to pull ahead of ℓ. If there is a matching that completely matches the latter side, then W can finish collectively in front of ℓ, and ℓ is not guaranteed promotion.

This could be extended easily if wins were 2 points instead of 3, but alas, 3 points causes the problem not to be convex, and we’re going to need some branching. The simplest branching method depends on the observation that it’s better for two teams to each win once and lose once against each other than draw twice. Hence, loop over all subsets of at most k choose 2 pairs of teams and run the algorithm above after marking each pair in the subset as having drawn once.

(I could propose improvements, but k is small, computers are cheap, programmers are expensive, and sports fans are relentless.)